# Xcode Objective C while loop cannot access global variables

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, while-loop

I'm very new to Xcode and Objective C. So most probably this is going to be an easy question (:

I'm trying to create an app that would do something if Caps Lock key is pressed.
And I need to see if Caps lock is pressed even if app is not in focus.
I've managed to check Caps Lock state even if my app is not in focus.

But I have an issue with getting out from while loop.
I cannot understand why my app cannot see what is happening to Caps lock key once it gets inside while loop.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _spam1 = NO;

     [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSFlagsChangedMask      handler:^(NSEvent* event){
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        if(event.keyCode == 0x39){ //CAPS LOCK key was pressed
            if([event modifierFlags] & NSAlphaShiftKeyMask){
                _spam1 = YES;
                NSLog(@"caps lock is on");
            } else {
                _spam1 = NO;
                NSLog(@"caps lock is off”);
            }

            //if I comment this part 
            //I can see if caps lock is on or off just fine
            while(_spam1){
                NSLog(@"Spam %@" , event);
                NSLog(@"Spam %lu" , [event modifierFlags] & NSAlphaShiftKeyMask);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
                 if([event modifierFlags] & NSAlphaShiftKeyMask){
                    //_spam1 = YES;
                } else {
                    _spam1 = NO;
                    NSLog(@“stop while loop”);
                    break;
                }
            }                            
        }
    }];       
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are blocking the runloop with your while,
make a method that has all the code inside the while loop, and fire it on timer - not to block the runloop - then it should work

Answer (score 1):

Work with framework, not agains:

Create a new subclass of NSView and override one of following methods. Set the new subclassed view in Interface builder. ( [read more in Event handling guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) )

So your code should look like this:

//multiKey handling

```
unichar SPACE_CHARACTER = 0x0020;

- (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    id responder = [[self window] firstResponder];

    if (responder != self)
    {
        return [super performKeyEquivalent:theEvent];
    }

    NSUInteger numberOfPressedCharacters = [[theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers] length];
    NSEventType eventType = [theEvent type];

    if (eventType == NSKeyDown && numberOfPressedCharacters == 1)
    {
        unichar key = [[theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers] characterAtIndex:0];
        if (key == SPACE_CHARACTER)
        {
            [self spaceBarPressed];
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

or

//single key handling (no modifiers like shift, ctrl...)

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
  // code belongs here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you have the `while` loop at all, as your code comment says it works without it?

In outline what is happening is as follows:

Your call to `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` requests the system to call the block you pass every time an event occurs (that matches). This is done *asynchronously*, and for this to happen you must be going around your *event loop*.

The standard application model is event driven, the system sets up the main event loop and calls your code to handle the various events - including any required calls to your event monitoring block. After your code handles the event it returns, the event loop goes around and obtains the next event, calls your code to handle it, etc., etc.

When your block is called it is passed a reference to the event it needs to process. In a single call that event will **not** be changed asynchronously by the system - the system obtains the event as part of the event loop processing and *calls your block*, until that call returns the event loop cannot continue.

So after all that preamble what happens with your `while` loop is the call to `sleepForTimeInterval` causes your application to pause within the call to the block - the block does not return and so its caller, the event loop, does not continue either. On waking up your loop continues to process *exactly the same event* it was passed when called, your block then continues around its loop getting nowhere...

HTH

Comment: I need a while loop because want I want to do is: When user presses caps lock I want to perform a certain action continiously with certain interval. Lets say I want to press a certain key combintaion is caps lock is on each second(or whatever user will set) UNTIL caps lock will be pressed again.

Comment: @Alex - you don't need a `while` loop, which is good as one won't work as you've found. When you get notification the caps lock is down first do your action and then use the GCD function `dispatch_after` to schedule a block to execute after your interval. That block should check if caps lock is still down and if so perform your action and call `dispatch_after` again. This way your periodic action is handled as a series of asynchronous events without blocking anything.

Comment: Wow, that nice... I'll try that. Thank you.